# Average value, standard deviation etc

Tags: c++, opencv

Hey i have to solve some problem. I load two images and convert them to float. And then i have convert the color space to Lab. i split the color space into channels.
now i want to subtract for every channel the average value from input(image) with the average value from input(image) (so the new average value is 0)
and divide input through there own standard deviation(so the new standard derivation is 0)

Do you have any advice how i can to that ?

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main() {

    //Bilder hochladen
    Mat input = imread("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\..\\input.png");
    Mat target = imread("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\..\\target.png");

    // In Fliesskommazahlen umwandeln
    input.convertTo(input, CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 255); 
    target.convertTo(target, CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 255);


    //Konvertieren Sie beide Bilder in den Lab-Farbraum

    cvtColor(input, input, COLOR_BGR2Lab);
    cvtColor(target, target, COLOR_BGR2Lab);


    vector<Mat> channels;
    split(input, channels);
    Scalar m = mean(channels[0]);
    

//My try to substrct the average value for every channel
        m[0] = m[0] - m[0];
        cout << m[0] << endl;

        m[1] = m[1] - m[1];
        cout << m[1] << endl;

        m[2] = m[2] - m[2];
        cout << m[2] << endl;



        




        cvtColor(input, input, COLOR_Lab2BGR);

    imshow("Ergebnis", input);
    waitKey(0);



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `m[0] = m[0] - m[0];` -- so you're effectively setting the mean you just calculated to zero by subtracting the mean from itself. (the others are somewhat redundant, since you only calculated mean of 1 channel mat, so they're already zero).

Comment: if i just use  `m[0] = m[0] - m[0]` i do it for every channel ? So i just need `m[0] = m[0] - m[0]` ? my english not the best but i try to understand

Comment: `x = x - x` is the same as `x = 0`. Your description says that this is what you want to do ("subtract for every channel the average value from input(image) with the average value from input(image)"), so my guess is that you have misunderstood something somewhere.

Comment: okaaay so its wrong. But how i can solve this problem --> now i want to subtract for every channel the average value from input(image) with the average value from input(image) (so the new average value is 0) and divide input through there own standard deviation(so the new standard derivation is 0)